# Ext.lang = function() to Ext.define

Tags: javascript, oop, extjs, refactoring, extjs4.1

I have an application which on launch does this ugly thing:

```
                Ext.lang = function (langId) {
                    if (Ext.local[langId]) {
                        return Ext.local[langId];
                    }
                    if (!localStorage.getItem('localLangBackup')) {
                        delete window.localStorage.localLang;
                        localStorage.setItem('localLangBackup', true);
                    }
                    return langId;
                }
```

I would love to refactor the thing to:

```
Ext.define('Ext.lang',{whatever gous in here...})
```

But so far no luck because when I try:

```
 Ext.define('Ext.lang', function (langId) {
        if (Ext.local[langId]) {
            return Ext.local[langId];
        }
        if (!localStorage.getItem('localLangBackup')) {
            delete window.localStorage.localLang;
            localStorage.setItem('localLangBackup', true);
        }
        return langId;
    });
```

I get

> Class.extend is not a function

Comment: Maybe this code executes before the entire extjs library is loaded. Make sure that you are executing this after fully loading extjs

Comment: No, this code snippet is before application load. So it has to be called before application. I need to move him to a js file so i can minify it. i could just move it, but it is UGLY!

Comment: You can't use code which is not loaded. It is that simple. Execute this code as the first thing after the extjs is loaded but before all the other application code is loaded.

Comment: Yeeeee, thank you. i added Ext.ready() before calling the function.... silly things...